# VBA Power Query refresh is slow in one PC (25 mins) and faster in another (3 mins)

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm working with a macro that refreshes Power query in another workbook. When tested in the first PC, it takes 3 minutes to complete the Refresh process. And this is exactly how long the manual refresh also take.

But when tested in the second PC, it's taking 25 mins at least. Both PCs are using Excel 365 but the 2nd PC has an Excel version that is based in Spanish. It's interesting to note that the second PC has more memory that the first. I have tried to disable other running programs like antivirus e.t.c but there's been no changes.

Here's the macro I'm using

```
For Each objConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        'Get current background-refresh value
        bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery

        'Temporarily disable background-refresh
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

          If Left(objConnection.Name, 8) = "Query - " Then
            Cname = objConnection.Name
                'Show the Query name that's being updated in the Status bar
                Application.StatusBar = "Refreshing ... " & Cname
            End If

        'Refresh this connection
        objConnection.Refresh

        'Set background-refresh value back to original value
        objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
    Next
```

Is there a way to fix the slow pace in second PC?

Comment: Are the same Target Workbooks in both PCs ? may be there is `INDIRECT()` function in the workbook in 2nd PC.

Comment: The same target workbooks are in both PCs that's why both completes the process. Just that one is slower

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell without some additional information about the data sources and Excel installations, but I faced a similar issue a couple of years ago and found two potential sources, that I would recommend to look into:

1: Latency. Depending on the number of reads in each connection and how they are performed (can't tell based on the information provided) latency between the client and the source system can have an exponential effect on the query. E.g. if each row in one query is used to perform a new call, delay will multiply based on latency.

2: Memory. The Excel (Office) installation. If the Excel version on the second PC is 32 bit, it doesn't matter how much memory it has. It can only use 2 GB in any case. I am not sure, but I believe that if Power Query loads to the data model on 32 bit installations, it will have a 1 GB data processing limit.

In either case, if your query takes 3 (or 25) minutes to run, it might be worthwhile to set up a view on the server or construct a joining query in the data connection, if the source is from a single server (or several servers in the same data center).

Comment: Jones thanks for that detailed reply. The data sources are csv files. Regarding the 2 suggestions provided, please let me know how I can check the latency. True, the first PC is 64 bit but I've not checked the 2nd.

Comment: You could ping the server, or just record it in the Immediate window and compare. Create this dimension before the For Each line: Dim TimeStart As Date Then add this before the Refresh this connection line: TimeStart = Now() And just after the objConnection.Refresh line: Debug.Print objConnection.Name & " elapsed time: " & Int(CSng((Now() - TimeStart) * 24 * 3600)) & " Seconds"  . Then just compare the value between PC1 and PC2. If they are similar, it is probably the Excel version. If PC2 is significantly higher, it is the connection/latency.

Comment: PS. It might actually make sense to compare with the latency as well, so you should ping the server anyway. Do that by running 'ping XX.XXX.XX.XXX' (replace the 'XXX' part with the ip address of the source system) in CommandPrompt . If you don't know the ip of the computer, then you may be able to find it by running 'ipconfig /all' and locating it somewhere in the response.